# PC VS MAR in Instruction Execution cycle

Tags: cpu-architecture, cpu-registers

As far as this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_cycle) shows, during the fetch cycle, PC sends its content to MAR which is connected to address Bus. Then the PC gets incremented.(As here, value is being copied, so no need of MAR if we directly connect PC with address bus).

My question is why PC is not directly connected with address bus? It will be much faster than the previous version. What special purpose is the MAR serving here?

Also same apply with MBR and IR, here data is copied from MBR -> IR. What am I missing here?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IR stores the current **instruction** being executed.

PC stores the **address** of the current instruction being executed. After the execution, PC gets the address for the new instruction. IR still contains old instruction.

IR and PC cannot access the address bus, only MAR and MDR can.

**PC and IR must interact with MAR and MDR because MAR and MDR are the registers that lie between the CPU and the data and address bus. Later on, we may decide to remove the MAR and/or the MDR for efficiency reasons.**

For more info, refer to this [link](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Overall/pc_ir.html).